# What's the meaning of Kryo.reference?

Tags: java, serialization, kryo

What's the meaning of `Kryo.reference()` ?

> By default, each appearance of an object in the graph after the first is stored as an integer ordinal. This allows multiple references to the same object and cyclic graphs to be serialized. This has a small amount of overhead and can be disabled to save space if it is not needed.

I'm puzzled about the above explanation. Should not be more savable when using `Kryo.reference` because it just using a integer to reference the object ?

Comment: Well, yes, it is. Suppose A has a reference to B, which has a reference to A. Now save A. You need to save A, and since A has a reference to B, save B, and since B has a reference to A, save A, and since A has a reference to B, save B, etc. etc.. Whereas if you use an integer, you save A, and since A has a reference to B, you save B, and since B has a reference to A and A has been saved already, you save the reference to A, and you're done.

Comment: @JBNizet, thanks for your answer. But what I feel puzzled is the follow sentence: `This has a small amount of overhead and can be disabled to save space if it is not needed.`

Comment: In memory, having cycles is not a problem. It becomes a problem when serializing. In memory, storing an integer reference 42, which then needs to be looked up in some dictionary to get the actual object A that is referenced by this integer reference 42, has an overhead compared to storing a direct reference to A in B.

Comment: Ok, I got it. That's meaning if you don't have any object which A reference to B and B reference to A, then using `kryo.reference(false)` will more savable and more faster. But if it is, we should use `kryo.reference(true)` (which is set default). Right ?

Comment: No idea about that. I don't even know what kryo is. Just explaining what the above sentene means.

Comment: That should be right--at least from what I can see, if you tell Kryo to store references to objects, somewhere it must have a big ol' Map<Object, Int> that keeps track of every object and its reference ID. That's probably the overhead they were talking about. However, in theory, if you reference an object often, it could perform better to have references because instead of reading/writing the same object, it just reads/writes a single integer.